# Why 'say "%hash"' does not work in the same way as it work for scalars and arrays?

Tags: perl

Why '**say "%hash"**' does not work in the same way as it works for scalars and arrays?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Modern::Perl;
use Test::More;

my $s = "Hello, World!";
say $s;
say "$s";

my @a = ("Hello", "World!");
say @a;
say "@a";

my %h = ("Hello", "World!");
say %h;
say "%h";

D:\TEST\perl>perl 1.pl
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
HelloWorld!
Hello World!
HelloWorld!
%h
```

Comment: @toolic Interpolation is performed by the `qq` operator (of which the double quotes are a special case).  `print` or `say` don't do the interpolation, they just receive the processed string and output it.

Comment: @Gordon `say` is part of the stable releases of Perl since 5.10.0, out on December 18th, 2007.

Comment: say "@list @{[%hash]}"'; # let the anarchy begin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it would screw up the `printf` syntax?

```
%d = ('key' => 'value');
printf "The answer is %d\n", 4;    # is %d a format symbol or the hash table?
```

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is a simple "because that's the way it is." Sigil % doesn't trigger interpolation in double-quoted strings.

I don't have the definite rationalization, but it could be a mix of the following:

- conflict with printf-style formatting
- there's no one way of doing it.  Would you prefer space-separated? Keys only? A different separator between pairs and a key and its value?